# Android browsing event hook

Tags: android

for some business application scenario, we need to make an application (or a background service/daemon) that sits on an Android device and is activated when person, using any Android browser, comes to a certain website. We control the website content and can put any HTML/javascript/something else in it if needed.

So the idea is that popup window with some message/choice is presented to the user when the user visits the website and clicks something. One idea, which I don't know if it is feasible, is to listen for all HTTP requests (if this hook exists somewhere in the SDK) and recognize an URL we are interested in, which would in turn trigger our application.

Any other ideas?

Kind regards,

Bozo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One idea, which I don't know if it is feasible, is to listen for all HTTP requests (if this hook exists somewhere in the SDK) and recognize an URL we are interested in, which would in turn trigger our application.

Fortunately, this is not possible.

You are welcome to create an application that has an activity with an `<intent-filter>` that identifies the URL you are interested in. Depending on how the user accesses the URL in question, they may get a choice of launching your app or one of their browsers. Users, of course, are perfectly welcome to ignore your app and load up the URL in a browser.

> Any other ideas?

Any solution would represent a security flaw in Android. Hence, I sincerely hope that you fail in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a proxy.

Orbot uses iptables to redirect to it's proxy service but it seems that not all Android distributions have the iptables module enabled so it might only work on rooted devices.

https://gitweb.torproject.org/orbot.git/tree/HEAD:/src/org/torproject/android